# How to rewrite this encoding for a UISwitch and also how to decode it?

Tags: swift, encoding, decoding, state-restoration

I'm trying to save the state of some switches and restore it when the app launches again but when I wrote this :

```
override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    coder.encode(Int32(self.runSwitch1.state.rawValue), forKey: CodingKey.Protocol)
}
```

I got this error :

> Cannot convert value of type 'CodingKey.Protocol.Type' to expected argument type 'String'

What should I do ?

Comment: use UserDefaults to store value..

Comment: The parameter after `forKey` must be a `String`, that's what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean't was restoring state between app switches provide a unique key against the type to be encoded

```
override func encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(self.runSwitch1.isOn, forKey: "switchState")    
  super.encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```

//Decode later when state restore

```
override func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {          
  super.decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```

And restore switch state by

```
override func applicationFinishedRestoringState() {
   let restoredState =coder.decodeBool(forKey: "switchState") 
   self.switch.setOn(restoredState, animated: false)
}
```

Use CoreData or other db based framework to sustain states even after app is closed. Or you can do it using userdefaults

```
class MySavedSwitchStates:NSObject {
    var userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    private override init() {
    }
    static let shared = MySavedSwitchStates()

    //This saves state to preferences
    func setSwitchState(_ state:Bool) {
        userDefault.set(state, forKey: "SOME_SWITCH_STATE")
    }

    //This retrieve the current state of switch
    func retrieveSwitchState() -> Bool {    
        return userDefault.bool(forKey: "SOME_SWITCH_STATE")
    }
}
```

and in your controller

```
//In your controller viewdidLoad
let restoredState = MySavedSwitchStates.shared.retrieveSwitchState()
self.switch.setOn(restoredState, animated: false)
```

Comment: Please don't use `value(forKey:)` in `UserDefaults`. There is `object(forKey:)` and for this case  `func retrieveSwitchState() -> Bool { return userDefault.bool(forKey: "SOME_SWITCH_STATE") }`

Comment: Then how do we get back a stored value from it?

Comment: Do you mean not to use string directly.. If that is the case , I did it for readability

Comment: I mean to use `bool(forKey` which returns the `Bool` value or `false` if the key doesn't exist.